# Why there is "??" before a filename

Tags: linux

I have a code that generates several output files. I saw that there are two question marks in my filename. For example, I am supposed to get a file named "output.txt", but actually I got "??output.txt". What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question marks are probably invalid Unicode characters. To find out precisely *which* characters, you could try `ls *output.txt | xxd`. That will tell you the UTF-8 bytes that make up the character(s). Then go to http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.html and paste in the hex values that `xxd` reported, making sure that you select "Hex UTF-8 bytes". You should see the Unicode codepoint of the invalid character(s) in the filename you're producing.